# kendo grid auto scroll on first click

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Only on first click on kendo grid widget (thead or tbody), the page scroll as shown on attached gif.

[image]

The problem is due to tabindex attribute added to table when 'allowCopy' is enabled.

Removing tabindex attribute in jquery, the scroll issue disappear, but copy doesn't work.

Any way to avoid this annoying behaviour?

Comment: You need to show us the code so that we can replicate the issue.

Comment: Does it occur in all browsers?

Comment: @SteveGreene only on Chrome and Opera. It doesn't occur on IE and Firefox

Comment: Is it marked Navigatable? That can cause issues like this on some browsers.

Comment: Tried also with navigatable explicitly set to false, but it doesn't solve.